# SQl SELECT Percentage

Tags: sql, select

have two three tables one for student, second for class, and the third for gender.  I am trying to get the total number of each gender and the percentage.  I used the following statment to get the number and it works well:

```
SELECT Gender.GenderName as Gender, COUNT(*) as cnt  
FROM         (Client INNER JOIN
             Gender ON Student.GenderID = Gender.GenderID)
             GROUP BY Gender.GenderName
```

I could not figure out how I can get the percenage, also how to make ClassName or ID as as selectable item to get the gender for each class or all classes by using @ClassId int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to a SQL Server right now but you use either `Cast` or `Convert` to convert to a floating type. Or you may want to refer to your SQL Server's documentation for its specific type conversion functions.

```
SELECT a.Gender, a.cnt, Cast(a.cnt as float) / b.cnt * 100
  FROM (SELECT Gender.GenderName as Gender, COUNT(*) as cnt
          FROM Client 
    INNER JOIN Gender 
           ON Student.GenderID = Gender.GenderID 
      GROUP BY Gender.GenderName) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM student) b
```

PS: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. `a.cnt/b.cnt` would do integer math and return zero if b.cnt > a.cnt (In this case it would be) ... we need to convert either `a.cnt` or `b.cnt` to a float so `a.cnt/b.cnt` becomes a float and then times it by 100 to give you the percent. Also, I missed that the GenderName had been aliased in the inner SELECT.

Comment: Thanks Nabheet, I got error Invalid column name 'gendername'.  In the Table it is GenderName, I chnaged it to GenderName still I get same error

Comment: I just suggested an edit to this answer since it was 99% correct. Basically, you need to change `as Gender` to `as GenderName` and then cast `b.cnt` to a floating type. The rest works fine.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I made the change, but I get the percentage as 0 (no column name).  Could you please explain how I could cast b.cnt to a floating type.